# Custom color and marker in ipython with pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm quite new to python. I'm using iPython with pylab for practicing. Now i can run and see

```
plot(p,sin(p), 'bx')
```

Again I can use

```
plot(p,sin(p), 'brown')
```

Now I want `brown x` markers

So, I tried

```
plot(p,sin(p), 'brownx')
```

and

```
plot(p,sin(p), 'brown', 'x')
```

I got errors. I googled but did not find anything either. I even tried `plot ?` but that wasn't affirmative too. But I may have missed.

Comment: Look at this page: http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html You may set marker type by `marker='o'` and color by `color='brown'`.

Comment: @Serenity, But I'm getting a continuous line.

Comment: @Serenity `plot(p,sin(p),'x')` and `plot(p,sin(p),marker='x')` are giving different figures.

Comment: Yep, because of 'x' means x markers without line.

Comment: @Serenity. I'm sorry, but I did not get you. Bother to explain a bit?

Comment: Well I guess this can make things more understandable. I get using bx imgur.com/a/ltRbM. But when I use color and marker I get imgur.com/a/xWKo0. Can you see the solid line in the second image? Can you say me how to remove that?

Comment: Set `linewidth=0` or just set `linestyle=''` in your code.

Comment: @Serenity. Yes! That is what I was looking for. Thanks for your valuable time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the detailed help about [`pylab.plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). According to this link:

> plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers
>
> plot(x, y, 'o')  # plot x and y using circle markers
>
> plot(x, y, 'b')  # plot x and y using blue solid line
>
> plot(x, y, 'ko:') # plot x and y using black dashed line with black circle markers

The last argument is the an optional format string.

However you may set manually line style, line color and marker type and other parameters of a plot with sufficient arguments like in this piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s, color = 'brown', marker='x', linestyle = '-', linewidth=1.)
plt.title('Sine line')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes! It's ok. But why I go on getting the solid line when I use marker='x'?

Comment: Just `plot(x,y,'x-') `or `plot(x,y,marker='x',linestyle='-')`

Comment: It was a misprint

Comment: I figured it works when you use the short code like `g-` means `green "-"` points.
But my question is to how to make `brown "-"` points

Comment: You can not short "brown"  you have set in plot function `color='brown`. Shortcut "b" in matplotlib means blue color.

Comment: Well I guess this can make things more understandable. I get using `bx` http://imgur.com/a/ltRbM. But when I use `color` and `marker` I get http://imgur.com/a/xWKo0. Can you see the solid line in the second image? Can you say me how to remove that?